# Syntax error in PHP 5.4.28

Tags: php, syntax-error, php-5.4

The following line gives error in 5.4.28

```
(new MySocketServer())->run();

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)
```

but it works in PHP 5.4.4

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you *100% sure* you are running PHP 5.4? This error almost always occurs when the OP thinks they are using one version of PHP but is using another.

Comment: Yes :

php -v

PHP 5.4.28-1~dotdeb.0 (cli) (built: May  7 2014 23:10:42) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

Comment: Use `<?php phpinfo();` to check your version on the web, it can differ from CLI.

Comment: PHP Version => 5.4.28-1~dotdeb.0

Comment: Couldn't reproduce it on php 5.4.9: http://codepad.viper-7.com/zk2xHE Please show more code

Comment: Works fine for me in *PHP 5.4.28-1~dotdeb.1* (a slightly different version). https://gist.github.com/salathe/32f1eecbb3acb12eb6be

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)